# Is it really necessary to define an endpoint when you call axios POST in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, http-status-code-404, endpoint

I'm facing an error `POST 404 (Not Found)` as shown in another question that I posted.

[Why does the axios.post return POST 404 (Not Found) error even when axios.get does return a valid value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57409292/why-does-the-axios-post-return-post-404-not-found-error-even-when-axios-get-do)

I was told that the reason why the `axios post` is not working even though `axios get` is working for the same address is that I need an endpoint for the POST method, which I haven't set.

I looked through several different pages, but I realized that defining an endpoint for POST method is not necessarily discussed, at least not explicitly using the word "endpoint".

http://blog.vuejoy.com/4-axios/

https://github.com/axios/axios

https://zetcode.com/javascript/axios/

Is it really always necessary to have an endpoint when you try to call a POST method?

If it is, where should I define the endpoint? Within the same vue file where I make the POST call, or should I create another file and define the endpoint there and import it to my main `App.vue` file?

If not, why does the axios.post throw an error `404 Not Found`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does the axios.post return POST 404 (Not Found) error even when axios.get does return a valid value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57409292/why-does-the-axios-post-return-post-404-not-found-error-even-when-axios-get-do)

Comment: In that question I didn't even know about setting an endpoint, whereas in this question my purpose is to ask about whether it is always required to define an endpoint, so they are 2 different questions. Could you drop the flag of duplicate, please?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it really always necessary to have an endpoint when you try to call a POST method?

*Endpoint* is just jargon for "end of a communication channel". In this context, it means "the function that is called on the server when a URL is called with a particular HTTP method".

So yes, you need something that will respond to the HTTP request with the data you want.

NB: This isn't specific to POST requests.

> If it is, where should I define the endpoint?

In the server-side code.

> Within the same vue file where I make the POST call, or should I create another file and define the endpoint there and import it to my main App.vue file?

No. You need to write code so the server responds to the request. You can't make that happen using client-side code.

Comment: Could you explain what server-side code in this context can be? I googled by myself and found this article (https://www.seguetech.com/client-server-side-code/), but with my current level of understanding it doesn't seem to me it is any of JavaScript or Vue or JSON files that I'm dealing with in my current working directory "```slutuppgift```", and it's hard to visualize what it is.

Comment: Well, no, I can't. You haven't so much as shared the URL you are making the POST request to.

Comment: Well, let me rephrase the question. Could you raise any daily-life example of server-side code? For example, in the real Twitter, which parts of it could be written in server-side code, in what programming language?

Comment: Almost all of it, and most of it has to be, and they can use absolutely any programming language they like.

Comment: You could use Node.js with Express. It could like look like `app.post('/addkweet', (res, req) => {addToDatabase(res.body.newKweet)})`

Comment: Yes, JavaScript via Node falls under "absolutely any programming language they like" … but since there is a server responding to GET requests, it would make sense to change that rather than creating something new.

Comment: Will it be something like creating "```api.js```" file which contains ```app.post('/addkweet', (res, req) => {addToDatabase(res.body.newKweet)})``` within it, defining how "addKweet" looks like, and then use it in my main ```App.vue``` file?

Comment: @ShinichiTakagi — No. **If** you are using Express.js, then you can use `app.post('/addkweet', (res, req) => {addToDatabase(res.body.newKweet)})` (so long as you define `addToDatabase` and load a suitable body parser). You almost certainly won't be putting that in a *new* file though. You definitely won't be using it in a `.vue` file, you need to add the ability for your server to recieve and handle a POST request to your server. Your client side code is already making a POST request.

Comment: If it's neither one of Vue file (.vue) and JavaScript file (.js), what kind of file will it be? I mean, how should the extention look like? How do I know if I'm using Express.js if I'm not aware of it? In what kind of folder should it be stored? ```node_modules```, ```src```, or anything else?

Comment: It might be a JS file … but I have no idea what you are using to host your API service. You might be talking to a third party. You might be running it yourself. You might be running Apache with a PHP backend. You might be running Node.js with Express.js. You might be running IIS with ASP.NET. You might be using a static server that is in no way at all designed to support POST requests and needs replacing with something completely different if you want to use them.

Comment: It's practice code which I'm working on in a local environment, ```http://localhost:8080/```. The backend is Node.js

Comment: @ShinichiTakagi — So edit the JS which runs the backend.

Answer (score 0):

In the question you are linking to, you are doing

`GET localhost:4000/somefile **.json** (a **file**)`

I assume it's because **GET** called on a .json file will be read by the server as "get the contents of somefile.json" which is okay, and it will return it.

However for POST, the server has no predefined response - you can't POST to a file. You can post to an endpoint. You need to create for example a `localhost:4000/addKweet` endpoint that will take your kweet and append your kweet on the server side with some type of file write operation.

Comment: How can I create an endpoint? Will I create an "```addKweet.vue```" or "```addKweet.js```"  file in the same directory? I googled about endpoint, but haven't found any concrete example. I appreciate if you explain it to me by showing an example, I mean in a form of some kind of "example code".